# How to read text file contents into a variable using Windows batch?

Tags: batch-file

I have attempted to duplicate the methods employed in other answers to this question on Stackoverflow, but none have worked for me.  I have tried:

```
@echo off
wmic product where name="BMNIA" get Name, Version>tmp.txt
type tmp.txt
REM setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
REM for /f "delims=" %%x in (tmp.txt) do set ver=%%x
set /p ver=<tmp.txt
echo ver: %ver%
REM endlocal
```

using both the redirect method and the for loop method, but each returns the following:

```
Name   Version
BMNIA  1.1.1.4
ver:
```

The type command shows that the script is able to read the file contents, but for some reason ver remains empty.  Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Don

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set PRODUCTNAME=BMNIA
set VER=
for /f "skip=1 delims=" %%p in ('wmic product where name^="%PRODUCTNAME%" get Version 2^> NULL') do (
  set VER=%%p
  if {!VER!} NEQ {} goto :BREAK
)
:BREAK
echo %VER%
endlocal
```

If the product is not installed, VER will be empty. If there are multiple matches, then VER will contain the version number of the first instance output by wmic.exe.

Comment: That worked.  Thank you very much!  I didn't realize that it was necessary to skip a line.  I thought the file read would continue until the end.  Nor did I understand (still don't) that the output of the wmic command needed to be redirected to NULL.

Comment: @Don this redirects not the output but the errors to NUL. Try it with a nonexistent productname and you will see why it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
set ver=not installed
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%p in ('wmic product where name^="BMNIA" get Version /value 2^>nul') do set ver=%%p
echo ver: %ver%

set ver=not installed
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%p in ('wmic product where name^="whatever" get Version /value 2^>nul') do set ver=%%p
echo ver: %ver%
```

Comment: For queries like this, you don't need the `find` command. As you are using the `=` as a delimiter and asking only for the second token, `%%p` will only be populated for lines with a `=` sign separating two elements. If `%%p` is not populated, the code in the `do` clause is not executed, that is, the line is ignored as it does not populate any of the requested tokens.

Comment: @MCND: you are right. I was so used to use `find` with it, that I never thougt about it.